# Docker SDK for Python: Create a mount of type bind for a service

Tags: python, docker, python-docker

I am trying to use the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/services.html) to create a service.

I need some mounts of type "bind" but I don't know how to specify this using the `client.services.create` command.
It only accepts a list of strings of format `source:target:options` where options can only be `rw` or `ro`.

The created mounts are therefore all of type "volume".

The result I am trying to achieve should be similar with what I can get using the Docker CLI with

```
    docker service create \
      ...
      --mount type=bind,src=/host/path,dst=/container/path
```

Is that possible? If so: how?

Comment: That syntax looks like the older `docker run -v` format; does `/host/path:/container/path` work?  In a Swarm context you may not know which specific node you're running on, does a bind mount actually make sense?